# (Cucumber/ ruby/ PageObject) Access input (form) element in an iframe/iframe with PageObject

Tags: ruby, iframe, cucumber, watir, page-object-gem

I need to access this element:

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9 ]*" name="card_number" id="card_number" autocomplete="off" size="22" class="input-outline-none">
```

It is placed in a second iframe like this (I put it simple not to have it too complicated):

```
<iframe scrolling="no" data-aura-rendered-by="203:0" id="<<iframe_id>>" src="<<iframe_url>>" width="100%" height="95px" frameborder="0">
#document
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC .....>
(...)
<iframe scrolling="no" id="<<iframe2_id>>" name="<<iframe2_name>>" src="<<iframe2_url"" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">
#document
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC .....>
(...)
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="javascript:void(0);" id="number-form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <label for="card_number" class="visuallyhidden" id="number_label">Card Number</label>
    <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9 ]*" name="card_number" id="card_number" autocomplete="off" size="22" class="input-outline-none">
    (...)
  </form>
(...)
</iframe>

</iframe>
```

I tried to access it like this (using Ruby/ cucumber/ waitr/ PageObject):

```
 in_iframe(:id => 'YPWNwIjOrg') do |outer_iframe|
    in_iframe({:id => 'spreedly-number-frame-9437'}, outer_iframe) do |inner_iframe|
      element(:cc_num, :id => "card_number", :frame => inner_iframe)
    end
  end
```

I get this error message:

```
with exception: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::IFrame: located: false; {:id=>"<<iframe_id>>", :tag_name=>"iframe"}> to be located
Browser driver used: #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x00007fc1e33d7910>
```

How to access it correctly?

Comment: The convention to treat iframes like this in PO gem really doesn't make sense since watir does all of this automatically. Please turn on the selenium logger and re-run so I can see what it's trying to locate. Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :info

Comment: What are the ids of the iframes? There seems to be a mismatch between the HTML/error and the page-object code provided. Your page-object code worked for me as long as the iframe ids were correct. Note that you probably want to use `text_field` instead of `element` so that you get the right getter/setter methods.

Comment: @Justin Ko: thanky you for your hint with "text_field".
Unfortunately the same error message occured ...

The id's are:
id1: <<iframe_id>>
id2: <<iframe2_id>>
Of course I used them correctly but just did not replaced them in the code fractal below ...

Comment: @titusfortner: where can I sent this?

(sorry, I am new to ruby, cucumber, po, ...)

Comment: @titusfortner: We are not using Selenium, but Watir, PageObject etc...
and log is set like this (before I posted this question here):`
@logger = Logging.logger(STDOUT)
@logger.level = :info

Watir.logger.level = :debug`

Comment: @Cybersphinx, Watir uses Selenium under the covers. You can put the logger line above the code that is failing to execute. Also, what version of Watir and Page-Object are you using? I seem to be missing something as I cannot get your exact error message.

Comment: Watir logger says:
2019-01-09 16:40:18 INFO Watir <- `Verifying precondition #<Watir::TextField: located: false; {:id=>"YPWNwIjOrg", :tag_name=>"iframe"} --> {:id=>"spreedly-number-frame-9437", :tag_name=>"iframe"} --> {:id=>"card_number", :tag_name=>"input"}>#wait_for_writable for send_keys`
2019-01-09 16:40:18 DEBUG Watir Converted {:id=>"YPWNwIjOrg", :tag_name=>"iframe"} to [:xpath, ".//*[local-name()='iframe'][@id='YPWNwIjOrg']"]

Comment: 2019-01-09 16:40:48 INFO Watir <- `Completed #<Watir::TextField: located: false; {:id=>"YPWNwIjOrg", :tag_name=>"iframe"} --> {:id=>"spreedly-number-frame-9437", :tag_name=>"iframe"} --> {:id=>"card_number", :tag_name=>"input"}>#send_keys`

Comment: @titusfortner: how can I check versions of Watir and PageObject?

Comment: Look for the gemfile.lock file to see what versions are being used. Watir logs provide info about building the selector and some code flow, what I'd really like to see are the commands being sent to the driver, which requires the selenium logging to be turned on. You can paste the code into a gist.github.com and reply with the link.

Comment: @titusfortner: Versions are:
watir (6.14.0, 6.12.0, 6.11.0)
watir-webdriver (0.9.9)
webdrivers (3.4.1, 3.3.2)
page-object (2.2.4)
page_navigation (0.10)

Comment: Selenium output:
2019-01-10 16:39:46 INFO Selenium -> POST session/a6bb2dc17962748306de2be601e8d87d/element
2019-01-10 16:39:46 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:9515/session/a6bb2dc17962748306de2be601e8d87d/element | {"using":"xpath","value":".//*[local-name()='iframe'][@id='YPWNwIjOrg']"}

Comment: 2019-01-10 16:39:46 INFO Selenium <- {"sessionId":"a6bb2dc17962748306de2be601e8d87d","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\".//*[local-name()='iframe'][@id='YPWNwIjOrg']\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.2 x86_64)"}}

Comment: I don't think Page-Object waits properly here, so maybe double-check it isn't a timing issue - eg put a `sleep(30)` before trying to access the frame. Maybe also check to see what iframes do exist - eg do a `p browser.iframes.map(&:id)`.

Comment: Regarding versions, please remove any watir-webdriver references from your gemfile, and ideally update to using latest watir (right now: 6.16.5). If you create a gist with all of the information, and then copy the gist link and paste it here. Pasting code in comments is difficult to read.

Comment: @titusfortner: What exactly do I need to paste into gist? Selenium log output or the gem versions or both?

Comment: @JustinKo: Good hint (wait()) - I had it (7 seconds waiting). I checked, the iframe and element were present before the script went further, but the result is that what I reported unfortunately.
I do not know how to handle with p browser.iframes.map(&:id)
Is that a line I can add before I try to access the element in my script?

Comment: @titusfortner & JustinKo
Thank you you guys for helping me!!!

Comment: `p browser.iframes.map(&:id)` will output the id attribute of each iframe on the page. Run it before the line you are having problems with. Your error message said the iframe couldn't be found, which makes me curious what does it see.

Comment: @JustinKo: Thank you! You were right! The ids change all time. So I need to address them in a different way. Is it possible with "index"? There are 2 iframes nested. Can I use my code above (someone said this is not a popper way to address iframe elements ...)?

Comment: Thank you very much! I found the solution:
browser.iframe(:index => 0).iframe(:index => 0).text_field(:id => "anything").send_keys "Content" worked!!!
This did not work:
browser.iframe(:index => 1).text_field(:id => "card_number").send_keys

Comment: @JustinKo: Thank you very  much for your help!!

Comment: @titusfortner: Thank you very  much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use
element.iframe(id: "idFrame").iframe(id: "idFrame2").input(id: "card_number")

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with "element." in front, you need to use "browser." instead as I mentioned before already.